# Workflow 4.0 service peristence

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I have flowchart workflow(4) services runnning on IIS, everything is working fine.  now trying for persistence on the same project, i want to add a code activity to persist the current instance based on some condition, Please provide code to save the current instance in sql store (db) I mean persisting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the current state of your workflow you need to add a Persist activity to your workflow. When it executes it will save the state in SQL server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. also please let me know how to reload the state in next instance. or am i in the wrong path.

Comment: Depends on your hosting model. With a WorkflowApplication there is a Load() method you pass the instance ID to load the state for.

Comment: I am hositing on IIS and exposed as WCF.

Comment: In that case all you need to do is sens a WCF request to the workflow and the WorkflowServiceHost will take care of the rest.